# Am I safe to copy my settings.py file which was generated offline to my remote server?

Tags: python, django

So I'm moving my project from my offline directory to my remote server on Digital Ocean. Is there anything I need to be concerned about? For example am I safe keeping the same `SECRET_KEY` that was generated offline? Anything else I need to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/#critical-settings) should answer this question :

> Make sure that the key used in production isn’t used anywhere else and avoid committing it to source control.

Also, don't forget to [set `DEBUG` to `False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/#debug).

Feel free to read the rest of this document. It tells you what to do (not hardcoding your `SECRET_KEY` for instance) and if can contain other useful informations for you.

---

An alternative I'd suggest would be to automate your deployment with something like [`Ansible`](https://www.ansible.com/) or [Puppet](https://puppet.com/).

With such software, you could easily :

- Automatically replace the `DEBUG` value to ensure it's `False`.
- Generate a SECRET_KEY value (automatically).

but in a general way it's perfectly ok to manually copy your `settings.py` and make the changes yourself. Just don't forget to change the values then.

Comment: Is it ok if I copy the whole contents of my project's `settings.py` (which includes `SECRET_KEY`) to my new `settings.py` on my server? There seems to be no other way to do it.

Comment: @Zorgan For convenience modify your `settings.py`, copy it, and then undo the changes  you made.

Comment: @Zorgan A `SECRET_KEY` is just a large random string. You can modify it as you want as long as is raisonnably large and random.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can copy the whole content of `settings.py`, but first remove the `SECRET_KEY` and set **DEBUG** to **FALSE**.

Comment: But then I won't have a `SECRET_KEY`? Or is there a way to generate a `SECRET_KEY` after that?

Comment: [Look at this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-SECRET_KEY-in-Django-actually-used-for)

Comment: Save the `SECRET_KEY` somewhere else on your PC or in any other file. However, without the SECRET_KEY, there will be plenty of errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not considered SAFE to use the same SECRET_KEY that you have used while developing.
you can do this in your **settings.py**

```
# SECRET_KEY = 'cg#p$g+j9tax!#a3cup@1$8obt2_+&k3q+pmu)5%asj6yjpkag'
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', 'cg#p$g+j9tax!#a3cup@1$8obt2_+&k3q+pmu)5%asj6yjpkag')
```

and don't forget to set **DEBUG = False**. Here's another way of doing it

```
# DEBUG = True
DEBUG = bool( os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', True) )
```

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment